# Using a pandas dataframe as a lookup table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a single row from dataframe `X`, what is the most efficient way to retrieve all rows from dataframe `Y` that completely match the query row?

Example: querying row `[0,1,0,1]` from

```
[
 [0,1,0,1, 1.0],
 [0,1,0,1, 2.0],
 [0,1,0,0, 3.0],
 [1,1,0,0, 0.5],
]
```

should return

```
[
 [0,1,0,1, 1.0],
 [0,1,0,1, 2.0],
]
```

`X` and `Y` are assumed to have the same schema, except that `Y` has an additional target value column. There may be one, zero, or many matches. The solution should be efficient even with thousands of columns.

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import pandas as pd

y = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 3],
                  'B': list('aac'),
                  'C': list('ddf'),
                  'D': [4, 5, 6]})

x = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a', 'd']],
                 columns=list('ABC'))

match = x.merge(y, on=x.columns.tolist())

match
#   A  B  C  D
#0  1  a  d  4
#1  1  a  d  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
L = [
 [0,1,0,1, 1.0],
 [0,1,0,1, 2.0],
 [0,1,0,0, 3.0],
 [1,1,0,0, 0.5],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(L)

Y = [0,1,0,1]


print (df[df.iloc[:, :len(Y)].eq(Y).all(axis=1)])

   0  1  2  3    4
0  0  1  0  1  1.0
1  0  1  0  1  2.0
```

**Explanation**:

First select first `N` columns by length of sequence:

```
print (df.iloc[:, :len(Y)])
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  0  1
1  0  1  0  1
2  0  1  0  0
3  1  1  0  0
```

Compare all rows by first row selected by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and `loc`:

```
print (df.iloc[:, :len(Y)].eq(Y))
       0     1     2      3
0   True  True  True   True
1   True  True  True   True
2   True  True  True  False
3  False  True  True  False
```

And check if match by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True`s per row:

```
print (df.iloc[:, :len(Y)].eq(Y).all(1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: can you explain the pandas expression?

Comment: @clstaudt - Yes, but after your data need check first 4 columns by your pattern? Because my solution match first row with all rows.

Answer (score 1):

One efficient way is to drop down to `numpy` and query individual columns:

Data from @jezrael.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abadef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,7,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,1,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,5,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

vals = df.values
arr = [4, 7, 1, 5]

mask = np.logical_and.reduce([vals[:, i+1]==arr[i] for i in range(len(arr))])
res = df.iloc[np.where(mask)[0]]

print(res)

#    A  B  C  D  E  F
# 0  a  4  7  1  5  a
# 2  a  4  7  1  5  a
```